# JavaFX Stage Modality

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a Modal window, opened through a Stage. This is the code:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();                               
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.setTitle("Stuff");
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.show();
```

But with no actual success, as I am able though, to click the underlying windows.
Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** 
I checked earlier the documentation at Oracle's site, but could find a solution, as the displayed window's behavior wasn't any close to what its expected from a Modal Window.
The JDK I am using on this project is 1.8.0_40

**EDIT 2:**
The code within the handle, as requested by ItachiUchiha

```
Boolean confirmacion = MessageUtil.ventanaConfirmacion(RecursosUtil.creaTextoProperties("confNoRealizar"));

if (confirmacion) {
    try {
        TbInspeccion inspeccionSeleccionada = (TbInspeccion) getTableRow().getItem();

        URL location = cargaURLFXML(OBSERVACIONESFXML);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = cargaFXML(location);

        stage = new Stage();
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("Observaciones");

        ObservacionesController controller = (ObservacionesController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.setStage(stage);
        controller.setInspeccion(inspeccionSeleccionada);
        controller.setProvider(provider);
        controller.setTablaPrincipal(tablaPrincipal);

        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

with

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

The former blocks as follows:

> Defines a modal window that block events from being delivered to its
>   entire owner window hierarchy.

Whereas the latter:

> Defines a modal window that blocks events from being delivered to any
>   other application window.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html

Depending on why you want to achieve the aforementioned behaviour you might want to use [JavaFX 8 Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) available from JDK 8 Update 40

Comment: I tried APPLICATION_MODAL as well, but still acting weird. I checked the documentation before making the question. But couldnt find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `stage.initOwner()` along with `Modality.WINDOW_MODAL` to that it identifies the owner :

```
stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

Or, you can just use `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` without an owner.

Comment: I tried both, but the window still isnt showing a "Modal" behaviour. Still acting weird. :(. Thank anyway for your fast response.

Comment: Where are you adding this code? Is it before `primary stage` is shown? Inside the action event of a button?

Comment: The code its part of a button handle present inside a TableCell

Comment: How do you get the reference to the current stage inside the Action Handler?

Comment: I have a TableView to which i add all columns after creating them.

Comment: Reference of the current Stage? Can you add everything that you have written inside `handle of the button of a  TableCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);`
with `stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

You also have to replace `stage.show();`
with `stage.showAndWait();`