# Can't update Label with String from Pagination createPage() funcion

Tags: java, javafx

Learning JavaFx, made another post recently

My problem: I have a label in my scene "editScene" which I want to update based on which edit button is pressed. Right now I have a Pagination of a ListView, (on my "displayScene") containing a Label, and two buttons, one being an edit button. When this is pressed, I would like to take the contents of the label before it, and output it onto the new label on the next scene. However it won't work. No matter what I can't update the label anywhere but initialize() which doesn't have access to the item I want. Below is all code that might be necessary.

```
@FXML
    public void initialize(){
        //input for schedule
        inputOutput = new InputOutput();
        schedule = inputOutput.inputSchedule();
        Collections.sort(schedule);
        //set mainView = mainImage
        mainView.setImage(mainImage);
        //set up display pages
        displayPagination.setPageCount((int)Math.ceil((double) schedule.size()/maxPerPage));
        displayPagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
    }
```

```
@FXML
 public void switchToEditScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("editScene.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

```
@FXML
    public Node createPage(int pageIndex){
        ListView<Event> eventView = new ListView<>();
        int fromIndex = pageIndex * maxPerPage;
        int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + maxPerPage, schedule.size());
        List<Event> eventString = schedule.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        //testing buttons
        eventView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Event>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Event item, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(item,empty);
                if(empty || item == null){
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else{
                    Label label = new Label(item.display());

                    Button editButton = new Button ("Edit");

                    Button completedButton = new Button ("Completed");
                    Label test = new Label(item.display());
                    editLabel = test;
                    editButton.setOnAction(event ->{
                        edittedTask = item;
                        try{
                             switchToEditScene(event);
                        } catch(IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    });
                    
                    completedButton.setOnAction(event ->{
                        System.out.println("done");
                        System.out.println(item);
                    });
                    
                    HBox eventHbox = new HBox(label);

                    HBox buttonHbox = new HBox(editButton,completedButton);

                    buttonHbox.setSpacing(50);

                    buttonHbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

                    HBox.setMargin(buttonHbox,new Insets(0,0,0,400));
                    
                    HBox hbox = new HBox(eventHbox,buttonHbox);
                    
                    setGraphic(hbox);
                }
            }

        });

        ObservableList<Event> observableEventList = FXCollections.observableArrayList((eventString));
        eventView.setItems(observableEventList);
        return eventView;
    }
    @FXML
    public void handlePreviousPage(){
        if(currentPage > 0){
            currentPage--;
            displayPagination.setCurrentPageIndex(currentPage);
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void handleNextPage(){
        if(currentPage < displayPagination.getPageCount()-1){
            currentPage++;
            displayPagination.setCurrentPageIndex(currentPage);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use a memeber variable, in which I assign item to, and then have a conditional checking if null in my initialize() and otherwise assigning the label, however the variable is always considered null, even tho after assigning variable = item, and then sout(variable) i can see it contains the data I need, just not when it gets to initialize()

also if u responded to my last post and wondering why I'm still using ListView i'll swap soon just got preoccupied with this.

Comment: I would suggest using a `Dialog`. Try to alter `Custom Login Dialog` from https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/.

Comment: If you do not use a `Dialog`, you will have to pass the data to the new view using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml). You will have to get the results back.  I would also recommend setting the stage initOwner and modality. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046945/javafx-stage-modality)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a `Dialog`. I edited the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77298240/left-justify-buttons-inside-of-an-hbox-inside-a-pagnition-if-that-matters) and [here](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;

public class App extends Application
{
    public class MyEvent{
        private final StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty(); 
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> when = new SimpleObjectProperty();
        
        public MyEvent( String title , LocalDate when ) 
        { 
            this.title.set(title);
            this.when.set(when);
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title.get();
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title.set(title);
        }

        public StringProperty titleProperty(){
            return this.title;
        }
        
        public LocalDate getWhen() {
            return when.get();
        }

        public void setWhen(LocalDate when) {
            this.when.set(when);
        }        

        public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> whenProperty(){
            return when;
        }      
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {        
        List<MyEvent> myEvents = new ArrayList();
        myEvents.add(new MyEvent ( "A bit of text" , LocalDate.now ()));
        myEvents.add(new MyEvent ( "Even more text than that." , LocalDate.now ( ).plusDays ( 1 ) ));
        myEvents.add(new MyEvent ( "Lots and lots and lots of text for a very long line." , LocalDate.now ( ).plusDays ( 2 ) ));
        ObservableList < MyEvent > events = FXCollections.observableArrayList(myEvent -> new Observable[]{myEvent.whenProperty(), myEvent.titleProperty()});
        events.setAll(myEvents);
        
        ListView < MyEvent > eventView = new ListView <> ( events );
        eventView.setCellFactory (( ListView < MyEvent > listView ) -> new ListCell < MyEvent > ( )
        {
            Button editButton = new Button ( "Edit" );
            Button completedButton = new Button ( "Completed" );
            Label label = new Label (  );
            Label labelTwo = new Label( );
            Region spacer = new Region ( );
            VBox vBox = new VBox(label, labelTwo);
            HBox rowBox = new HBox ( vBox , spacer , editButton , completedButton );            
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd");
            {
                // Mind the gap between label and buttons.
                HBox.setHgrow ( spacer , Priority.ALWAYS );
                rowBox.setAlignment ( Pos.CENTER );
                rowBox.setSpacing ( 7 );
            }
                   
            
            @Override
            protected void updateItem ( MyEvent item , boolean empty )
            {
                super.updateItem ( item , empty );
                if ( empty || item == null )
                {
                    setText ( null );
                    setGraphic ( null );
                } 
                else
                {                   
                    label.setText(item.getTitle());
                    labelTwo.setText("\tDue: " + item.getWhen().format(dateTimeFormatter));
                    editButton.setOnAction (actionEvent ->
                    {                        
                        System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Edit the Event: " + item.getTitle());
                        createCustomEditMyEventDialog(item);                     
                    });
                    completedButton.setOnAction ( actionEvent ->
                    {
                        System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Completed the Event: " + item.getTitle());
                    });
                    
                    setGraphic ( rowBox );
                }
            }
        } );

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane ( );
        pane.setCenter ( eventView );

        Scene scene = new Scene ( pane , 700 , 300 );
        stage.setScene ( scene );
        stage.setTitle ( "Schedule Example" );
        stage.show ( );
    }

    public void createCustomEditMyEventDialog(MyEvent item)
    {
        // Create the custom dialog.
        Dialog<MyEvent> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Edit Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Edit " + item.getTitle());


        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType doneButtonType = new ButtonType("Done", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(doneButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        // Create the username and password labels and fields.
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField tfTitle = new TextField(item.getTitle());
        tfTitle.setPromptText("Title");
        DatePicker dpDate = new DatePicker(item.getWhen());

        grid.add(new Label("Date:"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(tfTitle, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(dpDate, 1, 1);

        Node doneButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(doneButtonType);
        doneButton.setDisable(true);

        // Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
        tfTitle.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            doneButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
        });

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        // Request focus on the tfTitle field by default.
        Platform.runLater(() -> tfTitle.requestFocus());

        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == doneButtonType) {
                return new MyEvent(tfTitle.getText(), dpDate.getValue());
            }
            return null;
        });

        Optional<MyEvent> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        result.ifPresent(myEvent ->{
            item.setTitle(myEvent.getTitle());
            item.setWhen(myEvent.getWhen());
        });
    }
    
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch ( );
    }
}
```

[image]